# Is there any way to identify user is a MailUser or normal Cloud user in M365 using graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchangewebservices

Is there any way to identify user is a MailUser or normal Cloud user in M365 using graph api?

Comment: Are you trying to check if the user has a mailbox? I am trying to understand what you mean by normal cloud user.

Comment: @Danstan Yes, i want to check whether an smtp email address associated with mailbox or not?

Comment: you can see more on the problem which i am facing at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68313729/verify-a-smtp-address-is-associated-with-a-mailbox-or-not

Comment: Have tried MS Graph [GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)? This will return 404 for users that dont have mailbox. Will that work for you?

Comment: @Danstan Basically i have two users one is a MailUser and another is normal Cloud User(but do not have exchange license and MailBox), i have used the above method and i am getting the different errors for both the users, for MailUser error is "ResourceNotFound" and for the Cloud User "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI".

Comment: @Danstan i have tested this with V1 of graph api but when i test with Beta version i am getting the same error for both the user's that is "MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI". What is the difference can i rely on this error codes to distinguish these users?

Comment: There are two scenarios. Do you want users without a mailbox or users without a license that can activate a mailbox? Asking because even users who have not activated a mailbox will return 404 for mailbox settings